# Visual style of C++/MFC dialogs in Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

How can I control the visual style of C++/MFC dialogs in Windows 7?
[image]

The "Before" picture shows what I want, and this was the case until about a week ago. Now, my dialog appears as in the "After" picture, which is not what I want.

How can I control which style is used? I cannot find any manifest file, nor any option in the VS compiler or linker options, which controls this. My project is being built using MFC as a static library, and is not Unicode. It is being run under Windows 7.

64-bit Windows 7; Visual Studio Community 15.6.4; Windows SDK 10.0.16299.0

Comment: Your *"After"* screenshot has visual styles enabled, the *"Before"* doesn't. There are several ways to [enable visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx), and explicitly or implicitly disable them.

Comment: @Ilnspectable: My understanding is that Before is an example of the "classic" style, and After is a different style. I do want to have the ability to change styles enabled, but in the source code, say which kind I want (i e, Before or After). An additional point of confusion is that I had Before until recently, when After appeared for seemingly no reason, for every build.

Comment: I posted the link so that you know what changes to look for in your project. Things don't just change without a reason.

Comment: Consider to use a version control software such as GIT to track all the changes you make to your project over time. This would allow you to "go back in time" and find the last changeset where the bug didn't show. Compare with the next changeset to narrow down the changes that most likely caused the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the change probably occurred because of a change in VS and/or the solution targeting. As far as I can tell, the style is controlled by the commctrl DLL along with SetWindowTheme, and I did not change these. Can someone tell me how I can control the visual style, using the two examples I showed?

Comment: Well, did you change the target! Set it back.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances you have this in your source code somewhere. For me the system puts it in the `stdafx.h` File at the bottom:

If you have code like this then it will have visual styles:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
    language='*'\"")
```

If you want to switch it off, then the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx) in the comments to your question tells you how:

> You can turn off visual styles for a control or for all controls in a window by calling the `SetWindowTheme` function as follows:
>
> ```
> SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L" ", L" ");
> ```

Comment: The pragma can appear in any source file. The preprocessor conditionals aren't needed either. If you strip everything except for the final pragma, then that's what you are looking for. The `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is unrelated. It's not clear, why it should affect use of the Common Controls version 6 at all.

Comment: @IInspectable: I included the last pragma in one of my source files, but I still got After. For my situation, I want Before.

Comment: @Andrew Truckle: I had already tried this for a couple of individual controls, for which it does have an effect, but the result is not the same as the Before. And when I give it the m_hWnd for the main dialog, it has no effect on the dialog's controls, although it does affect the dialog window itself.

Comment: Have you tried doing a new project? And you should state what you have tried so that we know.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: No, I didn't try a new project. I am just asking how the style can be controlled, in either a new or an existing one. I have tried the suggestions here (manifest and SetWindowTheme).

Answer (score 0):

Without programming. You can get the the style back as before, by turning on the Reduced color mode in Compatibility Settings. (Righ click - Properties - Compatibility), Check if this is suitable for you.

[image]